# What does proof by appeal mean?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I had an exam with this question. I haven't been able to understand it. I understand the basic methods of proofs, but it's not clear to me how answer C is the correct choice here. It seems ambiguous what method of proof it's referring to. The option I chose was B.

Can someone clarify what part of the question indicates that C is the correct answer?
Thanks

**Question**

*It shall be shown that a statement B is valid if an assumption A is fulfilled. In the event of proof by appeal…*

**A** - …one leads the proof for the negated expression ¬Β ⇒ ¬Α.

**B** - …one shows the correctness of the statement to be proved in the form Α ⇒ Β.

**C** (correct) - …one assumes that the statement B is wrong and shows in the proof that this assumption cannot be true.

**D** - …one realizes the statement cannot be proven.

Comment: The phrase "proof by appeal" is entirely mysterious to me. I would suggest you consult your sources, i.e. your textbook or instructor or whatever other sources you are learning this material from.

Comment: Are you translating this from another language? If so it would be better to add the original text; someone here will be able to read it.

Comment: From context, it sounds like the phrase refers to proof by contradiction. It's also annoying that you're being tested on your knowledge of (apparently nonstandard) terminology *about* mathematical reasoning and not on your ability to actually *do* mathematical reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I'll check with the professor . I think you might be right that it's a translation issue. It's a German university, so it might make sense in German.